# R mutate recode

Tags: r, dplyr, recode

If I put together a simply data set, I have no issues recoding some values.

```
company <- c("A","B","C","D")
location <-c("MA","CA","DE","OH")
df1 <- data.frame(company, location)
df1

df1 %>% mutate(company=recode(company, 
                         `A`="Place1",
                         `B`="Place2",
                         `C`="Place2",
                         `D`="Place3"
                         ))
View(df1)
```

If I use the same logic on my data set 300K observations and 53 variables, it runs but no values convert.  I've reviewed for spaces etc for non matching values within the 'value' and did not find anything.

Working code

```
 Data_Long %>%
      mutate(Company=recode(Company,
                                     'COMPANY1 (THE)' = "NEWCOMPANY1",
                                     'COMPANY2' = "NEWCOMPANY2",
                                     'COMPANY3' = "NEWCOMPANY2"
      ))
    View(Data_long)
```

Comment: I sympathize, but it seems almost impossible to debug this remotely with no additional information.

Comment: You should provide us a sample of your data so we could help you. You may post `dput(head(Data_Long, 10))`.

Comment: What is the output from `unique(df1$Company)`?

Comment: See [MRE] to maximise the possibility of getting an answer.

Comment: there are 109 distinct values and 1760 in total, I'm only looking to convert a few critical values to account for M&A activity

Comment: Have you assign it back to `Data_Long`

Comment: ugh, TY akrun somehow slipped my mind